# How to go from exploratory factor analysis to generalised structural equation modelling?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I have conducted an exploratory factor analysis and discovered 4 factors. Previously I have used these factors in a logit regression analysis as independent variables, along with other independent variables to model a participation decision. However, I have seen that using generalised structural equation modelling would be a better way to go about this. I am struggling to understand how to do this.

From what I understand my four factor variables are my latent variables. But do I use them or are they estimated within the model with the variables that load highly on each one? And how then do I introduce the other independent variables into the model?

Any help would be appreciated, and if you could point me to some examples that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in Stata, where it's very easy to draw (and then estimate) the generalized SEM you describe using their SEM Builder tool. In the example below, I'm using a single latent regressor (built from a factor analysis of x1-x5) to explain the binary x10 in a logistic regression. To tell Stata that the regression has to be logistic, you draw in x10 as a "generalized response variable".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, I think I understand the basics of using gsem. Just a couple of short questions as I'm not sure I understand the relationship between factor analysis and gsem. Is the factor analysis used to inform the construction of the model but not actually used in the model ie. I don't see any way to inform the model what type of factor analysis to run? For multiple latent variables from the same group would I just connect the arrows from the variables that load highly to a latent variable in the factor analysis to that particular latent variable or to all of them?